# How to make my string a method I will call?

Tags: java, string, methods

Suppose I have strings.

```
String j = "objectName";
String i = "methodName";
```

How can I call a method:

```
objectName.methodName();
```

When I only have the strings for the names?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Reflections are the answer and this question can be marked as a duplicate. Thank you.

Comment: As a side note, when calling `invoke()`, if you have no parameters, just pass in null as one of them.